# Impute daily values based on erratic monthly data measures in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

So I have a dataset of water use which contains 3 key columns I want to manipulate looking like this:

```
   meter_read_date  meternumber  consumption
0        1/25/2011            1         4320
1        2/22/2011            1         3800
2        3/28/2011            1         4440
3        4/29/2011            1         4440
4         6/6/2011            1         5320
5         6/9/2011            1        20214
6        7/30/2011            1        20214
7        8/30/2011            1         2952
8        9/30/2011            1         3684
9       10/29/2011            1         3374
10      11/27/2011            1         3866
11      12/27/2011            1         3470
12       1/25/2011            3         5900
13       2/22/2011            3         5720
14       3/28/2011            3         7320
15       4/28/2011            3         6360
16        6/6/2011            3         9420
17        7/5/2011            3         8120
18        8/2/2011            3         8520
19        9/3/2011            3         6740
20      10/10/2011            3         6820
21       11/7/2011            3         5720
22       12/1/2011            3         3940
23      12/29/2011            3         6260
```

I would like to calculate the usage by calendar months for every meter number, which (I think) involves imputing average daily values and then aggregating the sum to a monthly scale.

To clarify, on row 1 consuption is 3800. This means consumption was measured as 3800 on 2/22/2011 and since the measurement before that came on 1/25/2011, we know that the 3800 gallons of water consumption happened from 1/26/2011 - 2/22/2011. I want to know the consumption by calendar month, so I would do this:

Consumption from 1/26/2011 - 2/22/2011 = 3800 gal over 28 days = ~146.2 gal/day

Consumption from 2/23/2011 - 3/28/2011 = 4440 gal over 34 days = ~130.6 gal/day

Therefore, estimated consumption from 2/1 - 2/28 = 146.2 gal/day and from 2/1-2/22 and 130.6 gal/day from 2/23-2/28 = 3216.4+783.6=4000 gal for the calendar month

I haven't been able to think of an efficient way of doing this without nested loops which I would really rather not use on a 1 million+ size dataset.
Any ideas?

Let me know if there's any other information I can post to be helpful.

Comment: what do you mean by normalize? such that the means are zero and standard deviation are 1?

Comment: I think the idea is that 3800 tells you the consumption from 1/25 to 2/22. The question is what is the consumption from 1/1 to 1/31, 2/1 to 2/28, etc.  Adding desired results to the question would clarify that.

Comment: Yeah sorry, JohnE is correct. I will clarify in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do most of what you want, although it's not going to be the most memory efficient way.  I'll elaborate on that below.

The first step is just to figure out daily consumption.

```
df.meter_read_date = pd.to_datetime(df.meter_read_date)
df['days_since'] = df.groupby('meternumber').meter_read_date.diff()
df = df.set_index('meter_read_date')
df['daily_consumption'] = df.consumption / df.days_since.dt.days
```

The dataframe now looks like this for the first meter.

```
                 meternumber  consumption  days_since  daily_consumption
meter_read_date                                                         
2011-01-25                 1         4320         NaT                NaN
2011-02-22                 1         3800     28 days         135.714286
2011-03-28                 1         4440     34 days         130.588235
2011-04-29                 1         4440     32 days         138.750000
2011-06-06                 1         5320     38 days         140.000000
2011-06-09                 1        20214      3 days        6738.000000
2011-07-30                 1        20214     51 days         396.352941
2011-08-30                 1         2952     31 days          95.225806
2011-09-30                 1         3684     31 days         118.838710
2011-10-29                 1         3374     29 days         116.344828
2011-11-27                 1         3866     29 days         133.310345
2011-12-27                 1         3470     30 days         115.666667
```

At this point there are at least two ways to proceed.  The most memory efficient way to proceed is by calculating what fraction of the daily consumption comes from each group but this is far from straightforward, especially since your data can have more or less than one reading per month.  So this way is (1) possible, (2) memory efficient, (3) relatively hard.

The other way is much easier and involves using `resample` to convert to daily observations and backfill daily consumption.

```
df_daily = df.groupby('meternumber')['daily_consumption'].resample(
                                        '1d',fill_method='bfill').reset_index()
```

The downside here is we have daily observations, putting more stress on memory, but it solves a lot of problems automatically -- no need to worry about how many days are in each month or how many readings were done in each month.  Here are a few rows, centered around one of the readings.

```
    meternumber meter_read_date           0
27            1      2011-02-21  135.714286
28            1      2011-02-22  135.714286
29            1      2011-02-23  130.588235
30            1      2011-02-24  130.588235
```

From there, all you have to do is aggregate.  (Note that the first and last months are based on partial data, you may want to either drop them or pro-rate the daily consumption.)

```
df_daily['month'] = df_daily.meter_read_date.dt.month
df_daily.reset_index().groupby(['meternumber','month'])[0].sum()

meternumber  month
1            1          950.000000
             2         3769.243697
             3         4072.720588
             4         4163.750000
             5         4340.000000
             6        29377.411765
             7        11985.814042
             8         2975.612903
             9         3565.161290
             10        3640.620690
             11        3946.379310
             12        3123.000000
3            1         1430.000000
             2         5786.050420
             3         6643.719165
             4         6227.593052
             5         7487.692308
             6         8169.230769
             7         9311.428571
             8         6716.696429
             9         5608.631757
             10        6133.243243
             11        5205.833333
             12        6424.166667
```

Some brief thoughts on an alternate approach:  If the above causes memory problems, I think there might be a hybrid approach.  Basically, after calculating the daily consumption, do a partial resample by adding the first and last day of each month.  From there you can probably aggregate in a similar way although you need to essentially do a weighted sum rather than simple sum.

It would still be a little harder to code than the above method, but would be much easier on the memory.  Still, doing it that way should simplify the coding considerably in that each row will now belong to a specific month and you wouldn't have to try and split readings across different months.

Comment: This looks like a pretty good solution. I will implement it and see how it goes, but can you also explain what '1d' means in the resample method?

Comment: @user2930124  '1d' just means 1 day for the frequency of the resample.  It can also just be written as 'd', the '1' is redundant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your dataframe's name is df and meter_read_date is a string/object type. since the dataframe has a date column, and you want to do some calculations by month, it's better to convert the date column to datetime(if it is not) and set the column as index.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
#  convert meter_read_date to datetime
df['meter_read_date'] = df.meter_read_date.apply(parse)
df = df.set_index(['meter_read_date'])

#  so you can group by year month and do some calculations
#  a datetime index have a convenient way to get its element:year,month,day, etc 
df.groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month,'meternumber'])['consumption'].mean()

# the result is :
      meternumber
2011  1   1               4320
          3               5900
      2   1               3800
          3               5720
      3   1               4440
          3               7320
      4   1               4440
          3               6360
      6   1              12767
          3               9420
      7   1              20214
          3               8120
      8   1               2952
          3               8520
      9   1               3684
          3               6740
      10  1               3374
          3               6820
      11  1               3866
          3               5720
      12  1               3470
          3               5100
Name: consumption, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @KevinBrown: I think the comments in this answer's code are probably enough of an explanation. While some extra prose might be nice, I don't think it's necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's add a column to the indicate month.  If your date column is a string, use method A.  If it is a datetime or timestamp, use method B.

Method A:

```
df['month'] = df.meter_read_date.apply(lambda date_str: date_str.split("/")[0])
```

Method B:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.meter_read_date).apply(lambda date: date.month)
```

Now, you simply need to perform a `groupby` on the meter ID and the newly created month.

```
gb = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['meternumber', 'month']).consumption.mean())
>>> gb
                       consumption
meternumber month             
1           1             4320
            2             3800
            3             4440
            4             4440
            6            12767
            7            20214
            8             2952
            9             3684
            10            3374
            11            3866
            12            3470
3           1             5900
            2             5720
            3             7320
            4             6360
            6             9420
            7             8120
            8             8520
            9             6740
            10            6820
            11            5720
            12            5100
```

You can also view this data relative to all the meters to help identify those with above avg. usage:

```
gb['monthly_avg'] = gb.reset_index().groupby('month').consumption.transform('mean').values
gb['relative_usage'] = gb.consumption / gb.monthly_avg

>>> gb
                   consumption  monthly_avg  relative_usage
meternumber month                                          
1           1             4320       5110.0        0.845401
            2             3800       4760.0        0.798319
            3             4440       5880.0        0.755102
            4             4440       5400.0        0.822222
            6            12767      11093.5        1.150854
            7            20214      14167.0        1.426837
            8             2952       5736.0        0.514644
            9             3684       5212.0        0.706830
            10            3374       5097.0        0.661958
            11            3866       4793.0        0.806593
            12            3470       4285.0        0.809802
3           1             5900       5110.0        1.154599
            2             5720       4760.0        1.201681
            3             7320       5880.0        1.244898
            4             6360       5400.0        1.177778
            6             9420      11093.5        0.849146
            7             8120      14167.0        0.573163
            8             8520       5736.0        1.485356
            9             6740       5212.0        1.293170
            10            6820       5097.0        1.338042
            11            5720       4793.0        1.193407
            12            5100       4285.0        1.190198
```